# Como incluir JQuery en el html

Tags: html, html5

Estoy intentando incluir un *css* desde un link externo, pero no logro conseguirlo.

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
</head>
```

¿Alguna idea, o acotación?

---

*Así es como se ve mal:*

[image: como se ve mal]

*Y así es como debería verse:*

[image: como debería verse]

Comment: Los estilos se agregan con la etiqueta link, y no la etiqueta script.

Comment: Esta pregunta esta mal redactada, es probable que decidan cerrarla por que no esta claro lo que se pregunta, y no agregas más infomación.

Comment: Como mencionó Luis , **los estilos externos se cargan con link** , `<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"`

Comment: @Dev.Joel, te recomiendo agregarlo como una respuesta "así sea una respuesta de tipo Wiki".

Comment: @Luis no entiendo como debo redactar la pregunta, estoy intentando incluir el estilo, pero no logro hacerlo, no se como hacerlo busque en google y me aparecia que con <script> por eso recurro a ustedes

Comment: Puedes leer esto, https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: y podrías agregar mas código. para saber el estado actual de tu pagina. De lo contrario tu pregunta va por el camino de ser cerrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En efecto la forma correcta de añadir hojas de estilos externos es con el tag `link`

> ¿ Por qué no carga los estilos ?

Al parecer la `URL` del `CDN` **es incorrecta**.

Al acceder a dicha `URL`  **recibe un error 404** , la `URL` alternativa sería :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

O  Cambiar la versión a `1.12.1`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```